# PDF hosted over REST interface returns ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in Chrome 88+

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I am working on a project that uses a Java Backend Application that hosts a PDF over a REST interface. Up to Chrome 87 and in Firefox this works perfectly fine. Since Chrome 88, however, I get this error:
[image: Chrome error message]

**Chrome Version:** 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I already tried:

- Disabling all browser extensions
- Setting a real filename for the PDF so it is hosted as /medias/sample.pdf?context=…
- Checking the [Chrome release notes](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#88). The “*Insecure downloads are blocked from
  secure pages, with changes through Chrome 88*” sounds suspicious, but
  then the PDF would have been blocked already in Chrome 87

Does anyone have the same problem or a hint on what the problem could be?

I can't post the link to the PDF itself, these are the Request and Response headers, though:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is coming  from csp sandbox header. I assume that chrome had some bug until now and it was fixed by this release, because by default pdf extension should be blocked by this header according to spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox

Pretty sure that it will be fixed if you remove sandbox mode for csp. You could also report an issue to chrome, to ask them whether this is expected behavior or some regression

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you! It is quite strange, however, that in Firefox viewing the PDF works with the header set to sandbox. Maybe it really is a bug in Chrome, I will open a ticket there.

Comment: Do you know why I still have ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error even without sandbox header? it is just happening on recent chrome 89

Comment: @CallMeLaNN, i'm also having this problem. Did you manage to find a fix for this? It only happens when i redirect to but if enter it in url, it somehow works. But in my case, i don't have a sandbox csp header

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer did you find a fix for this? I am stuck on the same issue and it works if I just paste the URL

Comment: same here, @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer would be very happy to learn about a fix or workaround

Comment: I still wasn't able to find a fix for it. In our case, since we're developing chrome extension instead of redirecting the usual way, we use `chrome.tabs.update` to update current tab or `chrome.tabs.create` to create a new tab.