# MS Edge (Chromium) do not display PDF documents with Content Security Policy set (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge, chromium, httpd.conf, content-security-policy

I have a web application that provides links to display PDFs.
The Content-Security-Policy is set in the apache configuration (httpd.conf)

My problem is now that in MS Edge (chromium based) is not opening/displaying the PDFs.
In Firefox on clicking the Link the new Tab is opened and the PDF gets loaded and displayed.
In MS Edge on clicking the Link the new Tab is opened but it is displaying an error:

```
example.domain.org is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

There is no extension installed, it is the same for incognito mode.
After testing the Content-Security-Policy it seems that the chromium based browsers do handle the CSP "sandbox" very different to FireFox. Without the "sandbox" policy it is working like in firefox.

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'self' example.domain.org.com; default-src 'self' example.domain.org.com; form-action 'self' example.domain.org.com; frame-src http://example.domain.org.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/css data:; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups;"
```

Is there a way to add the basic CSP sandbox (with specifiers like allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups) but still allow opening PDFs within the chromium based browsers?
Or to remove the CSP sandbox only for PDFs trough some config in httpd.conf?

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1187122) in chromium-based browsers. You can also refer to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/Abvu9qL-nzk) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205446/pdf-hosted-over-rest-interface-returns-err-blocked-by-client-in-chrome-88) which have the same issue. The issue seems to have been fixed in new version of chromium browsers, you can [download Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) which version is 92 to test.

Comment: @YuZhou: Thanks for pointing that it is a real bug! Seems I have to find a way to exclude somehow the PDFs form that policy with httpd.conf - as it is not foreseen for the users to update to canary or even another recent version.

Comment: I don't know if you can use `sandbox` with `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox`. If can't, then I think you can only try to find some approach in apache. I'm not familiar with apache, if you find one you can also put it as a solution here.