# Client browser security: URL to file VS URL link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

Is there any difference between URL which leads to a **file** (e.g. "https:// domain.com/path/to/invoice.pdf") VS URL to page (e.g. "https:// domain.com/path")?

*Problem:*

In Mozilla everythig works fine, but Chrome blocks redirect with error ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT and Safari opens a blank page. Examples of code I tried:

1.

```
window.open(linkToOpen, "_blank");
```

2. 

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.style.display = "none";
a.href = linkToOpen;
a.download = "file.pdf";
a.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```

...there are no plugins installed in Chrome. Also tried an incognito mode - same problem. Links work, but links to files don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF hosted over REST interface returns ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_CLIENT in Chrome 88+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205446/pdf-hosted-over-rest-interface-returns-err-blocked-by-client-in-chrome-88)

Comment: @somethinghere Unfortunately, no. I don't use the _CSP: sandbox_ header

Comment: It seems that in the comments, others are having the same issue and no resolution has been found yet.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is partially solved. Only for Chrome (not for Safari) and .pdf is opened in a new window.

As far as I understood, this is a problem related to .pdf URLs.

The solution:

```
const tempElement = document.createElement("a");
tempElement.style.display = "none";
tempElement.setAttribute("href", linkToOpen);
tempElement.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
    
// please note,
// that IE11 now returns undefined again for window.chrome
// and new Opera 30 outputs true for window.chrome
// but needs to check if window.opr is not undefined
// and new IE Edge outputs to true now for window.chrome
// and if not iOS Chrome check
// so use the below updated condition
const isChromium = window.chrome;
const winNav = window.navigator;
const vendorName = winNav.vendor;
const isOpera = typeof window.opr !== "undefined";
const isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1;
const isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");
const isWindowsChrome = isChromium !== null && 
    typeof isChromium !== "undefined" && 
    vendorName === "Google Inc." && 
    isOpera === false && 
    isIEedge === false;

if (isIOSChrome || isWindowsChrome) {
    // is Google Chrome
    tempElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
        shiftKey: true,
    }));
} else {
    // not Google Chrome
    tempElement.click();
}
tempElement.remove();
```

Michał Szarek from the last link below used

```
tempElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
```

...but this didn't work for me. I tried **shiftKey: true** and voila!

I don't understand why does this work, very interested in explanation.

A few links I used:

https://csplite.com/csp/test324/#bug_Chrome_iframe_PDF
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1187122
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/Abvu9qL-nzk